# SELECT query in WHERE clause of UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql error 1093 - Can’t specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

I am getting an error when putting SELECT query in WHERE clause of UPDATE query.

my Query is like this :

```
UPDATE `subschedulesseats` m
SET m.studentid='1'
WHERE m.`seatid`= (
    SELECT h.`seatid`
    FROM `subschedulesseats` h
    WHERE h.`sessiontime`='02:30~04:00'
    ORDER BY h.`seatid` ASC
    LIMIT 2,1
)
```

AND Error will be shown is like this :

"You can't specify target table 'm' for update in FROM clause"

I have attached a snap shot of the error display.

[image]

Please anyone can help me in this problem?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Please post the code directly instead of a (hard to read) screenshot. That will also help answerers copy and correct what you have.

Comment: you image is too cute :D

Comment: Here is it .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Sorry for bad image. I have updated my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you can update it by wrapping it in a subquery (*thus creating temporary table for the result*)

```
UPDATE `subschedulesseats` m
SET m.studentid='1'
WHERE m.`seatid`= 
(
    SELECT seatID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT h.`seatid`
        FROM `subschedulesseats` h
        WHERE h.`sessiontime`='02:30~04:00'
        ORDER BY h.`seatid` ASC
        LIMIT 2,1
    ) s
)
```

or by using `JOIN`

```
UPDATE  `subschedulesseats` m
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT seatID
            FROM
            (
                SELECT h.`seatid`
                FROM `subschedulesseats` h
                WHERE h.`sessiontime`='02:30~04:00'
                ORDER BY h.`seatid` ASC
                LIMIT 2,1
            ) s
        ) t ON m.seatID = t.seatID
SET     m.studentid = '1'
```

Comment: Yupyyyyyy....Thanks Dear It works perfectly as I need... Thanks Bro....

Comment: Using JOIN - worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
This behaviour is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

The reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498/1225190

Comment: You mean to say that We can't update the same table using select query? there is not a way to achieve this using single query

Comment: Please refer this answer dude... http://stackoverflow.com/a/45498/1225190  . this is a duplicate question