# Update with not in in clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause

From my perspective this query should work

```
UPDATE tab_antiguedad set rol_id = 4 
where ant_id = 29 
      and rol_id not in (
                         select rol_id 
                         from tab_antiguedad 
                         where usu_id = 55
                        )
```

`Where (select rol_id from tab_antiguedad where usu_id = 55)` here `rol_id` has 4 and 3.

But the mistake that throws me is:

> You can't specify target table 'tab_antiguedad' for update in FROM
>   clause

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you cannot update the same table you used in the select part.

UPDATE **tab_antiguedad**

set rol_id = 4

where ant_id = 29 and

rol_id not in (**select** rol_id from **tab_antiguedad** where usu_id = 55)

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Comment: I do not know much about subqueries, since I mainly use simple SQL commands, but I found a similiar question which I think that can help you. Just click [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283940/select-query-in-where-clause-of-update-query?lq=1) to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using alias

```
UPDATE tab_antiguedad as t1, (select rol_id 
        from tab_antiguedad   where usu_id = 55) as t2
set t1.rol_id = 4 
where t1.ant_id = 29 
and t1.rol_id != t2.rol_id
```

Comment: Gives the following error: You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Thank ScaisEdge, but strangely "not in" should not allow update if t1.rol_id is 3 or 4, by allowing the update?

Comment: Ok, I need you in the "not in" compare with all rol_id if one exists should not upgrade anything.

Comment: Could be not exists ... i have update the answer .. otherwise update you questiion with a proper, clear sample  ..

Comment: The problem is that t2.rol_id only shows "4" when it should show "4 and 3"

Comment: Ok then should be != t2.rol_id  ... i have update the answer

Comment: the process does not work because (select id from tab_antiguedad Where t2.rol t2.usu_id = 55) only issues you 1 record, and what I need is to send me the number of records there

Comment: Show a proper sample of data .. please because I can not understand